# Parsing HTTP status code

Tags: php, http, header, http-status-codes

I am using PHP to parse the numeric portion of the HTTP status code response.  Given a standard "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" response, I'd use:

```
$data = explode(' ', "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
$code = $data[1];
```

I'm not an expert on HTTP.  Would I ever encounter a response where the code is not at the position of $data[1] as in the above example?  I just want to be sure that this method of delimiting the response code will always work for any response.

Thanks, Brian

Comment: if your using cURL you could be like: curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); which will return 200 or whatever the http status is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When in doubt, check the spec.  The spec in this case, for HTTP/1.1, is [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).  In [Section 6.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6), it describes the *Status-Line*, the first component of a *Response*, as:

```
Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

That is - a single ASCII space (`SP`) must separate the *HTTP-Version* and the *Status-Code* - and if you check the definition of *HTTP-Version* (in [Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.1)) it cannot include a space, and neither can the *Status-Code*.

So you are good to go with that code.

Answer (score 7):

No if the webserver respect the standards doing an explode and caching the second item of the array is fine

if you really wants to be sure use a regular expression

i.e.

```
preg_match('|HTTP/\d\.\d\s+(\d+)\s+.*|',$subject,$match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

No, you would never encounter a response (if it's a proper HTTP response) which has a different format. See the [HTTP RFC (2616)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1).

Comment: See 6.1 Status-Line in both RFC 2616 (http 1.1) and RFC 1945 (http 1.0).  They both ensure this 3 parts, space delimited format.

Answer (score 2):

No, what you are doing is OK if all you want is the numeric. If however you want the message as well, you'll end up splitting it too, ie.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: To prevent that, I use the optional `$limit` argument like:

`$aHttpResp           = explode(' ', HttpComm::$headers[0], 3);      // HTTP/1.x ccc ~long description of the response~`